# ObjectInputStream and Apache-Commons-Net FTPClient

Tags: java, ftp, inputstream, objectoutputstream, apache-commons-net

I'm trying to read a file from an FTP server accessed with the FTPClient class from the Apache Commons library, but method to get a file `retrieveFile(remoteFileName, OutputStream)` needs an OutputStream. I'm trying to get the object without first writing the file to the disk. Is there any way I can get the ObjectInputStream to read from an OutputStream? Or some other way that I haven't thought of yet?

EDIT:
I've tried two ways:

```
public class FTPObjectReader
{
    public static Object read()
    {
        try
        {
            FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient(); 
            // Connect and stuff

            // Way one
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ftp.retrieveFile("Data.dat", baos);
            baos.close();
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
            ObjectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
            Object o = ois.readObject();

            // Way two
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(ftp.retrieveFileStream("Data.dat"));
            Object o = ois.readObject();
        }
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 0A
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.microgodrad.dev.Net.FTPObjectReader(FTPObjectReader.java:14)
    at com.microgodrad.dev.Net.main(Net.java:162) // File that calls this function
```

Comment: What object? Does the file you're retrieving really contain a serialized object?

Comment: Yes, I used an ObjectOutputStream to write in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then when it's closed wrap its byte array in a `ByteArrayInputStream` and wrap that in an `ObjectInputStream.`

Comment: When I perform `readObject()` on the ObjectInputStream I get a StreamCorruptedException.

Comment: Please post the entire exception, message, and stack trace, in your question; also the code you are now using.

Comment: Edited original question with your requested information.

Comment: @MicroGodrad If the file doesn't start with 0xAC it can't be the result of serialization. This one starts with 0x0A, which is a line feed. Examine your assumptions. Or possibly you need to set binary mode on the FTP transfer.